# Use my website's logged in user to share media on facebook, when two different users are logged in

Tags: facebook

I have used facebook login into my website and app. User can login using their fb account as well as can post their media to facebook from my website.

Scenario: In a single browser(say chrome) I am logged into facebook account using "xyz" account and logged in to my website using other account "abc".
When I click on "share" button on my website, it calls the facebook sharer and takes "xyz" user as creator of this new post, where as I want it to have "abc" posting this.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Having more than one FB account is not allowed anyway – so this problem could at most arise on a shared device. And there the solution is simple as well: _Log out_ of Facebook, before another user logs in.

Comment: @CBroe I have logged in my website myweb.com using one facebook account account ABC. then my website has the session for this first sign in. 

Then I log out of facebook.com from this account and sign in to facebook.com using another account XYZ.

Now myweb.com has ABC user logged in and facebook has XYZ.
And when i want to share mediar from myweb.com, it takes XYZ user as the sharer user in the facebook share dialog. It is happening.